# How can I get user's email? iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to get an user's email address that used in Mail.app.

How can I do it with the iPhone SDK?

Thank you!

Comment: I doubt this is possible. As a general rule, you can't access any user data without user intervention. It opens up privacy and security issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. You should prompt the user for their email address if you need it.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [ABGetMe](https://github.com/0xced/ABGetMe) for iOS. Specifically, the `AccountEmailAddresses` function returns the list of configured e-mail addresses.

Comment: +1 I checked it out yesterday after you tweeted about it. It uses private undocumented api so might get rejected for App Store releases as you mentioned on github page.

Comment: You can now disable private APIs in ABGetMe and it will fall back on a somewhat less effective method which does not use any private API.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to IOS, just assume that you are not allowed to do anything that is related to the private user info ( email address \ phone number )

another workaround is to save the user phone number and email address in the address book and get that from there