# Get iTunes user mail?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I would like to use the iTunes user mail account in order to synchronise some informations (with a server) accross different devices. This mail would be a convenient way to identify one user.

I didn't find a way to access it, is it possible to get it ? How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get user's email? iPhone SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708556/how-can-i-get-users-email-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iTunes user account is not visible to you programmatically. You can ask the user for their email address with the address book picker if you'd like to do it that way.